# MaybeInt to Int with elemIndex

Tags: haskell, types, option-type

I have a Table (list of list of string) and have a method "select" to remove certain rows. Select takes a column name and a value and removes all rows that don't have that value in that column. I used `elemIndex`, and get a type mismatch error (Maybe Int -> Int).

```
  type Field = String
  type Row   = [Field]
  type Table = [Row]

  select :: Field -> Field -> Table -> Table
  select column value table@(header:rows)
      = header : (filter rowHasValue rows)
      where columnIndex     = elemIndex column header
            rowHasValue row = (row !! columnIndex) == value;
```

I tried creating another function, but that gets a parse error on where

```
maybeValue :: Field -> Field -> Int
maybeValue column header = case maybeValue of
                                Just n -> n
                                Nothing ->
    where maybeValue = elemIndex column header;
```

Exact error message:

```
Main.hs:85:39: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Maybe Int'
    * In the second argument of `(!!)', namely `columnIndex'
      In the first argument of `(==)', namely `(row !! columnIndex)'
      In the expression: (row !! columnIndex) == value
   |
85 |             rowHasValue row = (row !! columnIndex) == value
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? `ghc` puts out a bunch of useful information the message, and saves us from guessing.

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Not trying to be snarky: have you tried to understand the error message? If so what do you think it's telling you and where are you confused? (reading error messages from the type-checker is an important skill)

Comment: That elemIndex returns a "Maybe Int", but (!!) simply uses an Int

Comment: I want to paraphrase what the compiler is telling you. I hope you'll find it helpful. "The `header` for the table might not have `column` in it anywhere. You have to tell me how you want `select` to behave when that happens, and you haven't done so."

Comment: If you actually finished the `case` expression (what is the value if you match `Nothing`?), you'd get rid of the parse error.

Comment: ah sorry, I see your issue was with the parse error rather than the type error (I should read more carefully myself)

Comment: Your maybeValue function also has the wrong type, header is a Row, not a Field.